# How to test whether class B is derived from class A?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

More specifically, let's say I have a class template with parameters `A` and `B`, and I would like to have a compiler error (when the template is being instantiated) if B is not derived from A.

```
template<class A, class B>
class Foo
{
    // static_assert(B is derived from A)
};
```

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan  MSVC2010 and g++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been asked so very many times before, but it's so simple I'll post the solution again:

```
~Foo()
{
    A* p = (B*)0; // B is required to be a subtype of A
}
```

Comment: I like this one for its simplicity. I was thinking way too complicated. :)

Comment: This doesn't work as a good test if `B` has a conversion operator to `A`.

Comment: See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f4599b11c9f593a9790951a4b0fb36d4-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) for why this is not the right way.

Comment: @rubenvb: My answer is perfectly fine.  A user-defined conversion from `B` to `A` does not create a conversion from `B*` to `A*`.  And your code snippet is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 9):

Check [boost::is_base_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html). And if you want to make it yourself try Alexyey's code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910979/how-is-base-of-works):

```
typedef char (&yes)[1];
typedef char (&no)[2];

template <typename B, typename D>
struct Host
{
  operator B*() const;
  operator D*();
};

template <typename B, typename D>
struct is_base_of
{
  template <typename T> 
  static yes check(D*, T);
  static no check(B*, int);

  static const bool value = sizeof(check(Host<B,D>(), int())) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

**Edit**. Writing static assert is not a big deal, but here it is:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(expr, msg) \
  { stat_assert<((expr) != 0)> ERROR_##msg; (void)ERROR_##msg; } 

template<int>
struct stat_assert;

template<>
struct stat_assert<true>{};
```

**Edit2.** And the whole working thing if you don't know how to merge these things: [Code on ideone](http://www.ideone.com/ZX0Jg)

Comment: This is elegant (I never saw this non-ellipsis way of doing SFINAE), but I'm tempted to down vote since it is not what OP wants: this does not trigger a compiler error when instantiating something with B and D such that B is not an accessible base of D.

Comment: Doesn't work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f4599b11c9f593a9790951a4b0fb36d4-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba

Comment: In C++11, this template is now available as `std::is_base_of` in header `<type_traits>`. The `static_assert()` function is also built into C++11, and like the example above, it requires a second argument that defines an error message.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something that uses SFINAE rules to make a template that will generate an error in the case that would normally be preferred, but can expand in another way as well.  I believe that boost may already have a template that does just that already.

Someone else gave you some code.  I'm leaving this answer because it explains how the code works.