# Check if template argument is inherited from class

Tags: c++, templates

I want to check if the type given to a template is inherited from a base class in my project.

It should work like one would expect it from the following example:

```
template< class T : public CBaseClass >
```

- Is it possible to do this with templates, if not, how else can I do it?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532281/how-to-test-whether-class-b-is-derived-from-class-a

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `boost::is_base_and_derived` from Boost, combined with `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`.  If you are using a compiler with TR1 or C++0x support, there are equivalents of those constructs in the standard library ([std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of), and the [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) statement in C++0x).

Comment: I'm not allowed to use boost, unfortunately

Comment: @Oktstrom: What compiler are you using?  Does it support TR1 or C++0x?

Comment: I'm using the compiler that comes with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: See if you have the `<type_traits>` header and the `std::is_base_of` template inside that.

Answer (score 14):

[Following](http://codepad.org/XdBKCAsh) an [example from Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#constraints):

```
template<class Test, class Base>
struct AssertSameOrDerivedFrom {
  AssertSameOrDerivedFrom() { &constraints; }
public:
  static void constraints() {
    Test *pd = 0;
    Base *pb = pd;
  }
};

template<class T>
struct YourClass {
  YourClass() {
    AssertSameOrDerivedFrom<T, CBaseClass>();
  }
};
```

In C++0x, this becomes:

```
template<class T>
struct YourClass {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<CBaseClass, T>::value);
};
```

Comment: @CrazyEddie: Given the code sample in the question, I believe the OP means "assert" by "check" rather than "do X if C, else Y".

Answer (score 6):

If you want to assert, do it Nurk's way.  If you want to check, use is_base_of from boost or C++0x.  If you can't use either of those, use SFINAE:

```
template < typename Base, typename PotentialDerived >
struct is_base
{
  typedef char (&no)  [1];
  typedef char (&yes) [2];

  static yes check(Base*);
  static no  check(...);

  enum { value = sizeof(check(static_cast<PotentialDerived*>(0))) == sizeof(yes) };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Shorter is better:

```
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
struct is_base {
    constexpr static bool check(Base*)   { return true; }
    constexpr static bool check(...)     { return false; }
    enum { value = check(static_cast<Derived*>(0)) };
};
```

Example 1:

```
struct A {};
struct B  : A { };

int main(void) {
    static_assert(is_base<A,B>::value, "If Error: A is not base of B");
}
```

Example 2:

```
template <bool, typename T=void>
struct Use {
    static std::string info() { return "Implementation that consider that A is not base of B"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Use<true,T>  {
    static std::string info() { return "Implementation that consider that A is the base of B"; }
};


int main(void) {
    std::cout << Use<is_base<A,B>::value>::info(); //Implementation that consider that A is the base of B
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution seems to be `std::is_base_of`:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<CBaseClass, T>);
```

You can of course also use it in combination with `if constexpr`:

```
if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<CBaseClass, T>) {
    //
} else {
    //
}
```

See cppreference for more details: 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

Comment: Yes, this is what you should do nowadays. Most of the other answers are just obsolete.