# Define template function only for classes derived from a single base

Tags: c++, templates

I have a base class `Base`, that a lot of other classes will be derived from. I would like to define:

```
template<typename Derived>
ostream &operator<< (ostream &o, Derived &derived) {
}
```

But only for classes derived from `Base`. I need all previously defined `operator<<` to be used for other types. How to do that? Is that possible?

I cannot create `ostream &operator<< (ostream &o, Base &base)`, because I need the exact type to be used in some type traits. Is there any way to "push" the derived type while passing the value as a base type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html

```
template<typename Derived>
typename enable_if<is_base_of<Base, Derived>, ostream&>::type
operator<< (ostream &o, Derived &derived) 
{

}
```

Comment: I prefer this one.  In both cases you'll get an error if you use it with the wrong type, but with this version you can override based on different criteria to catch the other kinds.  Based on the fact that `<<` is a popular operator, and you're doing this kind of thing, my select/case metafunction thingy might be of use.  http://crazycpp.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/28/

Comment: Just to clear some little things out: this function template is suitable for Base class too, not only for derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use type traits and SFINAE to let only classes derived from Base into your function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_and_derived.hpp>

struct Base {};

template<typename Derived>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_base_and_derived<Base, Derived>, std::ostream&>::type
operator<<(std::ostream& o, Derived& derived);

struct A : Base {};
struct B : Base {};
struct C {};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    std::cout << a << '\n'; // compiles
    std::cout << b << '\n'; // compiles
    std::cout << c << '\n'; // error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << c'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to derive from a marker template

```
struct Base { /* ... */ };

template<typename T>
struct BaseOutputtable {
  T *getDerived() { 
    return static_cast<T*>(this);
  }

 T const *getDerived() const { 
    return static_cast<T const*>(this);
  }

protected:
  ~BaseOutputtable() { }
};
```

Then derive them from both

```
struct MyDerived : Base, BaseOutputtable<MyDerived> {
  /* ... */
};
```

Now you can write it as

```
template<typename Derived>
ostream &operator<< (ostream &o, BaseOutputtable<Derived> &derived) {
  /* ... */
}
```

The advantage of this is its simplicity. And if `Base` is already templated it's even more useful (I take it that this is not the case for your code).

Comment: +1. I liked the idea. Very Good. More concrete way to resolve the ambiguities.

Comment: Instead of `getDerived`, you can also write user-defined conversion function, right?

Comment: @Nawaz that wouldn't work too well. Given a `BaseOutputtable<Derived>`, you would need to write `static_cast<Derived&>(derived)` to get a derived pointer or reference. And in that case, I believe it wouldn't even call the conversion function, but do the cast directly - since there is an inheritance relationship. So I cannot see a user-defined conversion function to be a useful replacement for the explicit member function call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_base_of` class template to ensure that only derived classes of `Base` can invoke `operator<<`:

```
template<typename Derived>
ostream &operator<< (ostream &o, Derived &derived) 
{
         static_assert<is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value>();
}
```

You can find the definition of `is_base_of` in another topic at stackoverflow itself: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910979/how-is-base-of-works)

And here is the definition of `static_assert`:

```
template<bool> struct static_assert;

template<> struct static_assert<true> {};
```

Comment: `static_assert` is of the form `static_assert(bool, const char*)`, that is, `static_assert(is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value, "Failed!");`

Comment: @DeadMG: I'm giving C++03 solution. See my solution now. It's complete.

Comment: wont it assert false the first time you use any non-derived type?

Comment: @aaa: That is what it meant for. To make it work only for derived classes of `Base`.

Comment: That does not solve the problem. This operator<< will override the std::ostream operator<< for every type, not just the types derived from Base. It will just raise a static assert.

Comment: but it will kill compilation as soon as anything matches the template. eg `int i; cout << i`

Comment: @Juraj: Did you even try? It will give compilation error, for other type!

Comment: @aaa: No. for `int`, there is a better match!

Comment: @Nawaz: the issue is that a compilation error is not SFINAE, therefore you cannot declare another `template <typename T>` for `T` which derive from `AnotherBase` because it'll clash at overload resolution.

Comment: @Juraj - The compiler is forced to use the closest match when there are multiple possible template resolutions.  All that has to be done is to have something less generic than 'T' as the parameter type.  You'd not be able to supply an alternative 'T' kind of overload or you'd get ambiguity errors.  You'd still be able to provide other, more specific (including non-template) overloads though.

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes I have tried that on g++ compiler and all types matched the template. Maybe I will have to try it again and check if I didn't make some miskate.