# template class restriction

Tags: c++, templates

I'm wondering if there is any way to restrict generating code for a template using custom conditions in my case i want to function foo to be called only if template class T has inherieted by class bar(something like this)

```
template <class T:public bar> void foo()
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You might be able to use Boost `enable_if`.

Comment: If you are dealing with public inheritance, then there is one more way. See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can restrict `T` though using "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error" (SFINAE):

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<bar, T>::value>::type foo()
{

}
```

If `T` is not derived from `bar`, specialization of the function template will fail and it will not be considered during overload resolution.  `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of` are new components of the C++ Standard Library added in the forthcoming revision, C++0x.  If your compiler/Standard Library implementation don't yet support them, you can also find them in C++ TR1 or Boost.TypeTraits.

Comment: Indeed, or if your `std` library doesn't have `is_base_of`, it's in Boost.

Comment: Yep.  The Boost equivalent would be `boost::enable_if<boost::is_base_of<bar, T> >::type`; the `std::enable_if` takes a `bool` as its first argument whereas `boost::enable_if` takes a type.  `std::enable_if` is equivalent to `boost::enable_if_c`.

Comment: do you have any idea how is the std library itself implemented enable_if or is_base_of classes?

Comment: There's a good answer to another question here on Stack Overflow that [explains how `is_base_of`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910979/how-is-base-of-works/2913870#2913870) works. `enable_if` is trivial: you can take a look at [the Boost `enable_if_c` implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/utility/enable_if.hpp) (It's the first two class definitions in that file; that's all there is to it. It defines a `::type` if the condition is true and it doesn't define it if the condition is false; that way, if the condition is false, the template can't be instantiated.).

Comment: Using return type for SFINAE is great! But in case of constructors it can't be used. I found that there's another trick, a dummy parameter with default value can be used instead, i.e. constructor_name(int normal_arg, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<bar, T>::value>::type* dummy = 0).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, following technique can be used (for public inheritance). It will cause an overhead of just one pointer initialization.

**Edit**: Re-writing

```
template<typename Parent, typename Child>
struct IsParentChild
{
  static Parent* Check (Child *p) { return p; }
  Parent* (*t_)(Child*);
  IsParentChild() : t_(&Check) {} // function instantiation only
};

template<typename T>
void foo ()
{
  IsParentChild<Bar, T> check;
// ...
}
```