# c++ Restricting multiple template class types to derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I was following [template class restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750793/template-class-restriction), but ran into errors in gcc:

error: multiple types in one declaration

error: declaration does not declare anything

It compiles if I remove the enable_if block. Can anybody explain if I am missing something?

```
template<class A, class B, class C, class D>                                                                               
typename std::enable_if<                                                  
std::is_base_of<baseofA, A>::value &&                      
std::is_base_of<baseofB, B>::value &&      
std::is_base_of<baseofC, C>::value &&            
std::is_base_of<baseofD, D>::value>::type       
class library {
    //whatever
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to have special behavior selected based on A,B,C and D or do you just want a compile time error if the condition fails?

Comment: I just want an error if the condition fails.

Comment: Then static_assert or (boost's static assert( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html)) is the correct tool for this problem. enable_if is mainly usesul to switch functions at compile time(for example see if you can memcpy a class instead of copy construct it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using `enable_if` correctly. `static_assert` would be more appropriate in this case.

```
template<class A, class B, class C, class D>       
class library {
  static_assert(
    std::is_base_of<baseofA, A>::value &&                      
    std::is_base_of<baseofB, B>::value &&      
    std::is_base_of<baseofC, C>::value &&            
    std::is_base_of<baseofD, D>::value, 
    "template argument A must derive from baseofA and so on ..." );
      //whatever
};
```

If you want to use `enable_if` instead you must create a dummy template parameter that depends on the enabled type for it to work as you desire.

```
template<class A, 
         class B, 
         class C, 
         class D, 
         class _ = 
           typename std::enable_if<                                                  
             std::is_base_of<baseofA, A>::value &&                      
             std::is_base_of<baseofB, B>::value &&      
             std::is_base_of<baseofC, C>::value &&            
             std::is_base_of<baseofD, D>::value>
           ::type>
class library {
    //whatever
};
```

But IMO, the `static_assert` method is better because you can provide a descriptive error message instead of the compiler complaining about failing to find a type named `type` in the latter case.

Comment: You're missing the second template argument of `std::enable_if`. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @mfontanini The second template argument is defaulted to `void`

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) page, try

```
template<class A, class B, class C, class D, class Enable = void>
class library;

template<class A, class B, class C, class D>                                                                      
class library<A, B, C, D, typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<baseofA, A>::value &&
                                                   std::is_base_of<baseofB, B>::value &&
                                                   std::is_base_of<baseofC, C>::value &&
                                                   std::is_base_of<baseofD, D>::value >::type
             >
{
    //whatever
};
```

Note that there must be something wrong with your example, since enable_if<>::type is a type, which you wouldn't want between the template<> line and the class library line.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I see now that the example I was following missed the last enable parameter.