# passing the type of a pointer as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I'll explain in an example:

```
template<typename T>
class Base{}

class A: public Base<A>{}

class foo(){
public:
   template<typename T>
   bool is_derived(){
      /* static check if T is derived from Base<T> */
   }
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770467/alternate-implementation-of-is-base-of-checking-base-derived-relationship) trait to determine whether a class is a base of another.

My question is, how can I send template arguments to is_base_of from T if T is a pointer without specializing the boo template function?

I'd like to do something like this:
if T is a pointer then `if (is_base_of<Base<*T>,*T>) return true;`
if T is not a pointer then `if (is_base_of<Base<T>,T>) return true;`

Comment: std::is_base_of<Base, typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>

Comment: Or simply `std::is_base_of<Base, std::remove_pointer_t<T>>` in C++14.

Comment: can it be Base or does it have to be Base<T> ?

Comment: @Loay My mistake. It has to be `Base<T>` as `Base` does not name any type in your example.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `std::remove_pointer` traits:

```
class foo(){
public:
   template<typename T>
   bool is_derived() const {
      using type = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
      static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base<type>, type>::value,
                    "type should inherit from Base<type>");
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it for me. On a side note, why can't i do type = std::remove_pointer_t<T>; what does the "using keyword indicate?

Comment: it is the c++11 `typedef` syntax for `typedef std::remove_pointer_t<T> type;`

Comment: Without this shortcut, you will have to write `std::is_base_of<Base<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>, std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::value`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have already answered yourself.

C++14

```
bool is_derived(){
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<Base<T>, std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::value );
}
```

C++11

```
bool is_derived(){
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<Base<T>, typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value );
}
```

C++03 - wrapper over `is_base_of` you mentioned (using [Boost.StaticAssert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html))

```
template<class Base, class Derived> struct my_is_base_of : is_base_of<Base, Derived> { };
template<class Base, class Derived> struct my_is_base_of<Base*, Derived*> : is_base_of<Base, Derived> { };

// ...

bool is_derived(){
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( my_is_base_of<Base<T>, T>::value );
}
```

Comment: You forget the `::value`, second argument for `static_assert` (at least for c++11), and `static_assert` is not available in c++03.

Comment: @Jarod42 Corrected that. Thanks.