# How to apply sizeof() operator to non-static class member methods?

Tags: c++, sizeof, member-functions

```
struct MyClass {
  int foo () { return 0; }
};

unsigned int size = sizeof(MyClass::foo);  // obviously error
```

Can we apply `sizeof()` to member methods from **outside** the `class` ? Do we need to declare object to get it ?

**Edit**: I know that above code will give error (that's why word 'obviously'). Wanted to know if we can at all apply the sizeof() to a member method. I don't want to describe the use case for that in length.

Comment: Why do you need the size of a function?

Comment: Only valid use I can think of is a JMP detour that also clears the entire function block...?

Comment: Note that you can't apply `sizeof` to a static member as it has function type anyway.

Comment: @Jesus, In template meta-programming, `sizeof()` trick is used often. I am aware of applying it on normal functions. Sometimes if I come across situation where I need to use it on member function, then how to do it?

Comment: @iammilind: That's nonsense code. You might want to explain what you are trying to do, rather that asking how to pursue your current attempt at doing it. _That said, I don't see how the downvotes are justified. (The same goes for the close-vote.)_

Comment: @sbi, I have already mentioned in the comment that it will give an error

Comment: 5.3.3 [expr.sizeof] "The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has **function** or incomplete **type**, or to an enumeration type before all its enumerators have been declared, or to the parenthesized name of such types, or to an lvalue that designates a bit-field." ... "The sizeof operator can be applied to a pointer to a function, but shall not be applied directly to a function." ... "The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and **function-to-pointer** (4.3) standard conversions are **not** applied to the operand of sizeof."

Comment: @iammilind: That tends to happen with arbitrary nonsense code. Which is exactly why I was asking what you, actually, tried to achieve.

Comment: @Charles, why is it a comment? In your comment, I get my answer.

Comment: @iammilind: Because it doesn't answer your question, it only says that I haven't understood your question or that your question can't be answered.

Comment: @iammilind:Well I can't think of a Use case where one would ever need to do this, but +1 just to nullify the downvote, which is not justified.

Comment: @Als: "can't think of a Use case"... it could give some insight into the cost of faulting in the code for a function function, or having that occupying cache, and whether to ask the compiler to consider inlining (or force it via a compiler extension), or in space/size tuning template instantiations versus other polymorphic and generic mechanisms.  If could also be relevant if you have say a SIGSEGV address and want to know if it falls inside a function's code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot obtain the size of a *member-function*, but you can obtain the sizeof a *pointer-to-member-function*:

```
int size = sizeof( &MyClass::foo );
```

The same goes for non-member functions (and static member functions), the size of the function cannot be obtained. It might be misleading because in most contexts, the name of the function *decays* automatically into a pointer to the function basically in the same way that an array *decays* to a pointer to the first element, but as in the case of arrays, `sizeof` does not trigger the decay and that in turn means that you have to *ask* for the pointer explicitly.

Comment: I think it's more helpful to refer to `&MyClass::foo` as a pointer-to-member. Pointers to member functions are a special case of pointer to members and are very different to "normal" function pointers.

Comment: Actually, I meant to applying `sizeof()` operator to the function. In my edit I misspelled as sizeof function. Which I have edited now.

Comment: @Charles: I do agree that in general *pointer-to-member*, but in this particular case the special case is not because it is a *member*, but because it is a *function*, the same issue would arise with a non-member function `sizeof( f )` would fail to compile in the same way. I don't think the standard makes a distinction when dealing with *functions* versus *member-functions* with respect to the `sizeof` operator. I have edited anyway hoping that it might be clear, if it is not feel free to edit or telling me. And thanks!

Answer (score 1):

iirc this would return size of function pointer anyways, so why do that? Or am I mistaken?

Edit: I was mistaken, this is invalid code, event if function were out of class. All you can do with sizeof and function is get size of function pointer(which you need to make first). If you want to get size occupied by function code you'll need some other way to get that.

Some further reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sizeof(int (MyClass::*)())
```

since you're taking the "size of a member **function pointer** of `MyClass` that returns `int` and takes no arguments".

Comment: So do we need to mention the `return` type explicitly; that's same as `sizeof(int)`. Is there a way by which we can write the name of the function and find it ?

Comment: @iammilind: No (unless you have C++0x), because the *entire point* of member function pointers is to avoid naming them. :) In C++0x you can *infer* the type, though, but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: @iammilind: You can just do `sizeof(&MyClass::foo)` if you're happy knowing the size of the pointer-to-member object.

Answer (score 1):

> Wanted to know if we can at all find the sizeof() a member method.

No, because the C++ language doesn't have such a concept. Or the size of any kind of function.

Comment: If you see my original post, I mentioned `applying sizeof() to function`

Comment: @iammilind I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: See how `is_base_of::value` is defined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910979/how-is-base-of-works

Comment: @iammilind `sizeof` is never applied to any function there. It's applied to a function *call*.

Comment: @iammilind: many traits templates use the size of the return type of a function call to determine their truth or falseness... combining this with SFINAE, or the allowed implicit conversion of `false` but not `true` to a pointer, is particularly useful in that varying which function is matched, and hence the return type, varies the size of the return type....