# Usage of CRTP in a call chain

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

In my widget library I'd like to implement some kind of call chain to initialize
a user supplied VIEW class which might(!) be derived from another class which adds
some additional functionality like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename VIEW>
struct App
{
    VIEW view;
    void init() {view.initialize(); }
};

template<typename DERIVED>
struct SpecializedView
{
    void initialize()
    {
        std::cout << "SpecializedView" << std::endl;
        static_cast<DERIVED*>(this)->initialize();
    }
};

struct UserView : SpecializedView<UserView>
{
    void initialize() {std::cout << "UserView" << std::endl; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Cannot be altered to: App<SpecializedView<UserView> > app;
    App<UserView> app; 
    app.init();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve some kind of call chain (if the user supplied VIEW class is derived from "SpecializedView") such that the output will be:

```
console output:

SpecializedView
UserView
```

Of course it would be easy to instantiate variable app with the type derived from
but this code is hidden in the library and should not be alterable.
In other words: The library code should only get the user derived type as parameter.

Comment: Explicit public initialization methods are very bad.

Comment: @DeadMG: The example code above was stripped down to a minimum obviously! I didn't want to add more code than necessary to describe my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write another function that calls `initialize()` on the class and on the base class if it exists and defines an `initialize()` method, too:

```
template <class T>
void callInitialize(T* t) {
    t->initialize();
    IF_EXISTS(base_class<T>::bc::initialize)
        callInitialize<base_class<T>::bc>(t);
}
```

Of course, the order of the calls can be reversed.

See [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/257288/946850) on the implementation of `IF_EXISTS`. Also, `base_class<T>` is not a standard construct, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8709830/946850) suggests that this cannot be done automatically.  The semantics would look like this:

```
template<T>
struct base_class<T> {
    typedef void bc;
};

template<>
struct base_class<UserView> {
    typedef SpecializedView<UserView> bc;
};
```

Perhaps your framework permits a semi-automatic way to do this.