# decltype in class method declaration: error when used before "referenced" member is declared

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Consider the [following code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cfd277617e00b2a44f732c31987c4229-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba):

```
struct test {    
    auto func() -> decltype(data) {}  // ERROR

    int data;
};

int main() {
    test t;
    t.func();
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
main.cpp:2:29: error: 'data' was not declared in this scope
     auto func() -> decltype(data) {}
```

However, if I place `data` above `func()`, it gives out no error ([live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=35ac9f2af265f0e38d8ee72678df4135-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)):

```
struct test {    
    int data;

    auto func() -> decltype(data) {}
};

...
```

And so my question is, why is `decltype` not considering members declared after it (when `decltype` is used in a method declaration, not in the definition)? I also want to know if there are any change in this behavior in future iterations of the language standard.

---

<sup>Please note that I'm asking this because I was expecting `decltype` to behave differently. My coding convention is to place class data members below the class functions. Surely this different behavior would affect how I organize my class members. I would be very grateful if you can provide any workaround that would preserve my coding convention.</sup>

Comment: Sorry - the nature of C++, inherited from C.

Comment: It's not just `decltype`, even a simple `typedef` shows the [same behavior](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8f959fbd70b0b7d44c21ff0d71967fd5-6f7ec8a47f20223a17b26973b6e13527). Moving the `typedef` above the member function definition will obviously fix the problem.

Comment: @Praetorian So it's an inherent problem... Too bad.

Comment: @Mark Garcia, it is sort of beneficial in fact, forcing programmers to write understandable code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trailing return type is part of the member function *declaration*, which does not have access to data members or member functions declared after it, unlike the member function *definition*, which does. I am not aware of any change in this behaviour in C++14.

See 3.4.1-7 of the C++11 standard, *Unqualified name look-up*:

> A name used in the definition of a class X **outside of a member function body** or nested class definition
>   shall be declared in one of the following ways:
>
> - before its use in class X or be a member of a base class of X (10.2), or...

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Also see the definition of a class member's scope in 3.3.7/1.