# Return type deduction with a private member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, c++14, return-type-deduction

As was explained in this [Q&A yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766137/decltype-in-class-method-declaration-error-when-used-before-referenced-member?rq=1), both g++ 4.8 and Clang 3.3 correctly complain about the code below with an error like "'b_' was not declared in this scope"

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(): b_(0) {}

    auto foo() const -> decltype(b_) // just leave out the -> decltype(b_) works with c++1y
    { 
        return b_;    
    }    
private:
    int b_;
};

int main() 
{
    Test t;
    std::cout << t.foo();
}
```

Moving the `private` section to the top of the class definition eliminates the error and prints 0.

My question is, **will this error also go away in C++14 with return type deduction**, so that I can leave out the `decltype` and have my `private` section at the end of the class definition?

**NOTE**: It [actually works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=874afeaf38f6079982522d02d792a7c0-085d7ad819eddc76e51a40f64ccc318f) based on @JesseGood 's answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, but there not anymore is a need for this because you can say

```
decltype(auto) foo() const { 
    return b_;    
}
```

This will deduce the return type automatically from its body.

Comment: I thought the new syntax was gonna be `auto foo() const() { return b_; }`, but I need to say `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: `decltype(auto)`... that's not the proposal I heard.  Gonna have to read the committee draft.

Comment: Also, it shouldn't fix the error this question is concerned with.

Comment: `decltype(auto)` means that unlike `auto`, you get a reference type if  what you return is a reference member. I.e you get `decltype(expr)` semantics (which is what the question does, too).

Comment: Yes, but `auto` isn't a valid expression, it's a placeholder for a type.  Didn't know it could combine with `decltype` this way.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's why `decltype(auto)` is a special form of the decltype specifier and not to be confused with the syntax that accepts a expression.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think this should work fine. Member function bodies are parsed only when the class is completely defined. Till then, the function has a placeholder type, and afterwards, the `b_` can be found and the function gets its final type. Is there something I missed?

Comment: @BenVoigt you just need to be careful not to have forward references to that function, then. I.e this is ill-formed: `struct A { void g() { f(); } decltype(auto) f() { return 0; } };`

Comment: +1 and now accepted. It's nice to know that `decltype(auto)` is actually different from `auto` alone. And a more banal reason is that my Clang 3.3 build from a few weeks back only works correctly with `decltype(auto)` and not with `auto` when trying to return a `std::make_pair` of two `vector` iterators.

Comment: Just running ahead of the new GotW series: what do you recommend, always `decltype(auto)`, even for functions returning by-value? I only wanted to use this to return a pair of iterators (by-value), so simple `auto` would be equivalent, right?

Comment: @rhalbersma i don't know what's the better of the two. Perhaps I would use `auto` by default (it's nice because you easily see when it's a reference and when not and *you* who write the code can decide it). And use `decltype(auto)` only when forwarding return values when delegating a function or operator call (i.e `decltype(auto) operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }`) when eventually *other* classes decide what form (reference/const/etc) of return is best.

Comment: And what is the type of `decltype(auto) f() { return f() + 42; }`?  At the start of the member function body the containing class has to be a complete type, but it isn't because we don't know the type of its member f yet.  Is this speculation, or is it actually an accepted part of the new draft?

Comment: @user1131467 this code is ill-formed (and makes no sense because it doesn't terminate). A function with deduced return type can be recursive, but it must have a way to deduce the return type in one of its terminating cases (and that case must be written first in the code). I recommend you to start a new question if you are interested in details.

Comment: Placeholder types.... making C++ type system more complicated than ever.  But it appears to DWIM so hurray!

Comment: The new feature is described here: [N3638](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html), and was adopted at Bristol.  My theory is that the committee enjoys torturing compiler authors.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so, because C++14 will have automatic return type deduction. The following compiles with g++ 4.8 by passing the `-std=c++1y` flag.

```
auto foo() const
{ 
    return b_;    
}
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know g++ 4.8 already had that flag, thought it was g++ 4.9 only. It indeed works like I want to.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, it can be declared after since that rule does not apply.

Comment: on second thought, I'm changing my acceptance to the answer of litb because the `decltype` is actually what I need (this was only a toy example).

Comment: @rhalbersma: In the original proposal, `decltype(auto)` was not decided yet. However, it was included in the [accepted proposal](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3638.html) which I was not aware of. +1 to litb's answer for teaching me.

Comment: it's nice to have all these features already when it's not even 2014 ;-)