# How do I retrieve the type of the base class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor, c++03

For this particular project, I am not able to use C++11 features (e.g. `decltype`) because the compiler does not yet support them. I need to be able to provide the current class as a template parameter, preferably within a macro without an argument (see below), without dressing up the `class` declaration or hiding curly braces, etc.

```
class Foo: private Bar<Foo> {
   MAGIC //expands to using Bar<Foo>::Baz; and some others
   public:
      void otherFunction();
      //... the rest of the class
};
```

Ideally, I'd like this to work very much like Qt's `Q_OBJECT` macro, but without introducing another pre-compile step and associated generated classes. `typeid` might be useful at runtime, but my goal is to accomplish all of this at build.

How do I write the `MAGIC` macro so that I don't need to repeat the class name each time?

Comment: This question seems to be the C++03 version of "[Can I implement an autonomous `self` member type in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21143835/560648)"

Comment: Mind if I change the title to *base clase*?  *enclosing class* makes it sound like you are nesting and what the type off the outer class.

Comment: The `self` question does look very similar, but it doesn't look like any of the proposed solutions work in C++03, as you noted.
Certainly change the title if it will make it more clear.

Comment: In C++ one has to ask *which baseclass?*

Comment: And my 2 cents are: It's probably not possible; instead of strong-arming a macro system which was not designed for it, either run your code e.g. through a perl script; or find a different solution which uses C++ (e.g. use a unique int as template argument, not a typename).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709340/can-the-type-of-a-base-class-be-obtained-from-a-template-type-automatically

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
protected:
    typedef Base<T> MagicBaseType;
    namespace Baz { }
};

class Derived1 : private Base<Derived1>
{
    using MagicBaseType::Baz;
}


class Derived1 : private Base<Derived2>
{
    using MagicBaseType::Baz;
}
```

or, if you can't modify the Base definition, using templates and multiple inheritance

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
protected:
    namespace Baz { }
};

template<typename T>
class DerivedTemplate : public T
{
protected:
    typedef typename T BaseType;
}

class Derived : public Base<Derived>, public DerivedTemplate<Base<Derived>>
{
using BaseType::Baz;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "proxy"(?) struct for Building up the inheritance:

```
template <typename S>
struct Base : public S{ //always public, access is restricted by inheriting Base properly
    using super = S;
};
```

Usage would be as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename S>
struct Base : public S { 
    using super = S;
};

template <typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    virtual void f() { std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;  }
};

class Foo : private Base<Bar<int>>
{
public:
    virtual void f() 
    { 
        std::cout << "Foo";
        super::f();  //Calls Bar<int>::f()
    }
};

class Fii : private Base<Foo>
{
public:
    virtual void f() 
    {
        std::cout << "Fii";  
        super::f(); //Calls Foo::f()
    }
};


int main()
{
    Fii fii;
    fii.f(); //Print "FiiFooBar"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any language supported mechanism to extract the base type from a class. You can use:

**Option 1**

```
class Foo: private Bar<Foo> {

#define BASE_TYPE Bar<Foo>
   // Use BASE_TYPE in MAGIC
   MAGIC //expands to using Bar<Foo>::Baz; and some others
#undef BASE_TYPE

   public:
      void otherFunction();
      //... the rest of the class
};
```

**Option 2**

```
class Foo: private Bar<Foo> {

    typedef Bar<Foo> BASE_TYPE;

   // Use BASE_TYPE in MAGIC
   MAGIC //expands to using Bar<Foo>::Baz; and some others

   public:
      void otherFunction();
      //... the rest of the class
};
```

Comment: You could avoid the redundancy by `#define`ing `BASE_TYPE` _before_ the class declaration, so you can say `class Foo : private BASE_TYPE`.

Comment: Or keep it in the class and use `typedef` instead of `#define` like `typdef Bar<Foo> BaseType;`

Comment: @RyanHaining, that's why I have the `#undef` right after the `MAGIC` line.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't care about formatting or writing a maintenance headache you can do this without repeating the type by having the macro take the type argument:

```
#define MAGIC(BASE) \
BASE { \
    using BASE::baz;

class Sub : private MAGIC(Base<Foo>)

  public:
    void otherFunction();
};
```

but this makes me feel pretty bad about myself