# Why doesn't compiler help us with type traits instead of resorting to language quirks?

Tags: c++, std, type-traits

Type traits are cool and I've used them since they originated in boost a few years ago. However, when you look at their implementation (check out ["How `is_base_of` works?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910979/how-is-base-of-works) StackOverflow thread).

Why won't compiler help here? For example, if you want to check if some class is base of another, compiler already knows that, why can't it tell us? This would make things like concepts so much easier to implement and use. You could use language constructs right there.

I am not sure, but I am guessing that it would increase general performance. It is like asking compiler for help, instead of C++ language.

I suspect that the primary reason will sound something like "we need to maintain backwards compatibility" and I agree, but why won't the compiler be more active in generating generic templated code?

Comment: You will be glad to know that now the compiler is required to help with that (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types#Type_traits_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29)

Comment: Thanks for the link. So this is no longer real template function, it is more of a compiler magic keyword hint? And it probably resolves to returning false in case the compiler is not C++11 compatible?

Comment: If the compiler is not C++11 it will not have that, obviously.

Comment: It can be.  But the point of those hacks was that compilers NOT designed specifically to help can still be convinced to give up the information.  So we do not have to convince every compiler vendor to implement it: it was already there. Compilers are free to hard code them now that they are in the standard, or they could just use the hack and keep their own code simpler.

Comment: It's just evolution. Early on, nobody realized that those traits were universally desirable features. Then people discovered how to implement them in the existing language. Since the C++ standard strives to "capture existing use", many traits have now become part of the standard. Others may be added in the future if there's demand.

Comment: Also, the performance improvement would at best affect the compilation time of course. Type traits can't do anything that copy-pasting code couldn't do.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't see anything in the link you posted that explicitly requires compiler help (although that is an obvious solution, and would certainly improve compile times if the templates are extensively used).

Comment: This is part of C++ as part of the C++ standard library, insofar it is a "language construct" no matter how it is implemented. One should not need to care. `std::string` is part of the language too, regardless how it is implemented. There is no performance (other than maybe compile-time) difference between a template implementation and a built-in either. Regardless, much of what's new in C++11 is built into compilers (for example, GCC wraps a lot of that stuff to built-ins).

Comment: @JamesKanze I guess I should have said "the implementation is required to help".

Comment: @Kerrek: I think "nobody realized" is probably a bit of a reach.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel: Well, yeah... I suppose "type traiting hadn't widely entered the community's vocabulary at the time of the first standard", if you prefer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually... [some do](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20101129/036967.html).

The thing is that if something can be implemented in pure C++ code, there is no reason, other than simplifying the code, to hard-wire them in the compiler. It is then a matter of trade-off, is the value brought by the code simplification worth the hard-wiring ?

This depends on several points:

- correctness (some times software may only partially emulate the trait)
- complexity of the code ~~ maintenance burden
- performance
- ...

Once all those points have been weighted, then you can determine whether it's more advantageous to put things in the library or the compiler; and the more likely situation is that you will end up with a mixed strategy: a couple intrinsics in the compiler used as building blocks to provide the required interface in the library.

Note that the maintenance burden is much more significant in a compiler: any C++ developer sufficiently acquainted with the language can delve into a library implementation, whereas the compiler code is a black-box. Therefore, it'll be much easier to debug and patch the library than the compiler, so there is incentive *not* to put things in the compiler unless you have a very good reason to.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an objective answer here, but I suspect the following.

1. The code using language quirks to find out this stuff has often already been written (Boost, etc).
2. The compiler does not have to be changed to implement this if it can be done with language quirks (which saves a lot of time in writing, compiling, debugging and testing).

It's basically a "don't fix what isn't broken" mentality.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler help for type traits has always been a design goal. TR1 formally introduced type traits, and included a section that described acceptable incorrect results in some cases to enable writing the type traits in straight C++. When those type traits were added to C++11 (with some name changes that don't affect their implementation) the allowance for incorrect results was removed, effectively **requiring** compiler help to implement some of them. And even for those that can be implemented in straight C++, compiler writers prefer intrinsics to complicated templates so that you don't have to put a drip pan under your computer to catch the slag as the overworked compiler causes the computer to melt down.