# Check if the type comes from a given parent type

Tags: c++, inheritance

**Simplifed example of my problem :**

I have an abstract class `A`. I have two abstract classes `B` and `C` inheriting from `A`. And I have a lot of final classes inheriting from `B` or `C` :

```
class A;
class B : public A;
class C : public A;
class B1 : public B;
class B2 : public B;
class C1 : public C;
class C2 : public C;
```

I implement an algorithm recieving a pointer of `A` having to know if the type comes from `B` or `C` to work properly :

```
void algorithm(boost::shared_ptr<const A> a)
{
  if(*a is a B instance)
    // do something
  else if(*a is a C instance)
    // do something other
}
```

**How can I check that simply without C++11 ?**

I know how to check the final type with `typeid(*a) == typeid(C1)`, but I don't know how to check a parent type...

Comment: maybe see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910979/how-does-is-base-of-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dynamic_pointer_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/):

```
if (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a)) {
   ...
}
else if (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<C>(a) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hum... This is C++11, but it's also defined in boost. It seems so simple !
Is it also a good way to test the final type ? Or the check with `typeid` is better ?

Comment: If you want to know exact type, use typeid. But to comply to Liskov substitution principle it's better to use dynamic cast. Since instances of B1and B2 should work just as B so it should not matter if it instance of B or if it one of subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dynamic_cast`.

```
 if (dynamic_cast<B *>(a))
 {
      //   // a actually points at a B, or something derived unambiguously from B
 }
```

Of course, more generally, you need to revisit the design of your function.   More often than not, it would be better that it not need to know about classes derived from `A`.   Avoiding that usually means using `A` as a polymorphic base that provides an interface to all functionality needed in the function (e.g. set of `virtual` functions that classes like `B` and `C` might specialise for themselves).

Comment: You're right. But actually it's for a dump/load process having to know the real type of the object in order to be able to reallocate it with the exact type.